A prospective longitudinal study with time dependent covariate
My question is similar to
Sample size calculation for multivariable Cox regression for treatment comparison.
I have a prospective longitudinal study over three years. The purpose of the study is to see if the event variable can be predicted by a time-dependent covariate (there is a possibility that we could also include the second time-dependent covariate in the model). We have discerned time survival as there are a limited number of time points as the patient comes to the clinic every four months to do a test. We will have censor data. (there is no pilot data for this study).
What kind of design could this study have and how could the sample size be calculated?
